# How is array representation using pseudocode?

Tags: arrays, pseudocode

I have this pseudocode array here, but I do not get it does it mean that array C has ten elements which are 1 2 3...10 ? if that's the case, then isn't it so that count is always false and therefore assigned to 0? then what's the point of such algorithm?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, these numbers can be any ten *distinct* numbers (according to the algorithm), and count is not of boolean type so it never returns false, unless you implement it in a language that considers zero as false, that is ;)

Comment: I still dont get it, what does "number of elements of C less than myNumber" mean?? what value it is?

Comment: the number of elements of C is always 10 right? then number of elements of C will never be less than myNumber...

Comment: It would be the count of the number of elements in the C array where their value is < myNumber.

Comment: one more thing, by "distinct initial value" it means that there will not be two 2's in the array at the same time right?